# (Swift2.3)Accessing class instance from another class

Tags: xcode8, swift2

New to Swift. I am trying to control the playback of background music on my app. I currently have the music starting up in my MainTabController. It plays as expected when I navigate through the rest of the VCs. I would like it to stop when certain VCs are shown, however.

I have my MusicHelper class set up.

```
class MusicHelper {
static let sharedHelper = MusicHelper()
var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer?

func playBackgroundMusic(file : String, repeats : Int) {
    let aSound = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(file, ofType: "mp3")!)
    do {
        audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL:aSound)
        audioPlayer!.numberOfLoops = repeats
        audioPlayer!.prepareToPlay()
        audioPlayer!.play()
    } catch {
        print("Cannot play the file")
    }
}

func togglePlayer(){
    if((audioPlayer?.playing) == true){
        audioPlayer?.stop()
    }else{
        audioPlayer?.play()
    }
}
}
```

How I start the music initially in my MainTabController:

```
class MainTabController: UINavigationController {

var bgMusic : MusicHelper = MusicHelper()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // other code
    bgMusic.playBackgroundMusic("music_background", repeats: -1)
}   
}
```

I am trying to access this same instance of bgMusic, but it is returning nil. My assumption is that I am actually making a new instance of the MainTabController? If so, how would I go about accessing that same instance of MusicHelper?

```
class VideoViewController: OrientationLockedVC {
    //Other code
    var mVC : MainTabController = MainTabController()

    func onImage() {
        //other code
        mVC.bgMusic.audioPlayer!.stop()

        // other code
    }

}
```

I'm not getting any explicit errors, but if I set a break point I can clearly see that the audioController is nil.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer?` for `public static var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer?`

and to call

```
if MusicHelper.audioPlayer != nil{
 MusicHelper.audioPlayer.stop()
}
```

Comment: This mostly worked. Thanks. Changed it to public static. Had to add MusicHelper.audioPlayer to the rest of the funcs. Wasn't able to call it how you suggested though. Had to call it though an instance of MusicHelper(bgMusic). I'm also using this to trigger sfx, not sure if that made a difference, but regardless, I've finally got it working. Thank you again.

Comment: You're welcome ;)
In this link you will find more details of methods and variables static. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html